# Creating NSString results in null

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to initialize an `NSString`. I tried `initWithString:` but this becomes invalid because the `NSString` becomes an `NSPlaceholderString`. I switched to `UTF8string`, but it returns a null value.

code below:

```
- (void) test:(NSString*)thing {
    id (*p_objc_msgSend)(id p, SEL sel, ...);
    id (*p_objc_getClass)(const char *s);
    Class class;

    p_objc_getClass = objc_getClass;
    p_objc_msgSend = objc_msgSend;

    NSString *s;

    class = (*p_objc_getClass)( "NSString");
    //SEL init = @selector(initWithString:);
    s = (*p_objc_msgSend)(class, @selector(alloc));
    s = (*p_objc_msgSend)(s, @selector(initWithUTF8String:), "AAA");

    NSLog(@"Value of %@", s);
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in such a bizarre way? Why don't you simply replace all of the above with `NSString *s = @"AAA";`?

Comment: What is wrong with `NSPlaceholderString`?

Comment: It's not creating the string with this practice

Comment: the first s line is returning null

Answer (score 0):

NSString is a class cluster with multiple private subclasses. NSPlaceholderString is a subclass of NSString so you can continue to use that object as any other NSString.